# getting error : table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns :

1. college (**cname** , state , enrollment)

   student (**sid** , sname , gpa , sizehs )

   apply (**sid** , cname , major , decision )

i tried this query :

```
select j.major , max(j.gpa)
from (select s.* , a.cname , a.major, a.decision 
        from student s join apply a on s.sid = a.sid and decision = 'y') j
group by major
```

this works. but when i add one more feild to select , it breaks :

```
select major , sname , max(gpa) , (select avg(gpa) from j) as avg -- trouble
from (select s.* , a.cname , a.major, a.decision 
        from student s join apply a on s.sid = a.sid and decision = 'y') j
group by major
having max(gpa) < avg;
```

i get an error saying: **table j doesn't exist**. why does this happen ? 
 If **j** doesn't exist then in the first query when i say `j.gpa` etc , it works. 
My aim is to find `Majors whose applicant's maximum GPA is below the average` , i made a query which works :

```
select major , sname , student.sid , gpa , 
    (select round(avg(gpa),5) as avg from student join apply 
        on student.sid = apply.sid and decision='Y') as avg
from student join apply on student.sid = apply.sid and decision='Y'
group by major
having max(gpa) < avg
```

but here , i have to type the join part both in `select` and `from` . i was hoping there would be some way to skip having to type the join part two times , so i came up with the (erroneous) query above.

any help would be great.

Comment: First, you should not use avg as a field alias name, it's a function. Second, you should use AS keyword when aliasing tables. Adding brackes also helps.

Comment: Did you tried with alias name?

Comment: at the point when mysql interprets your query especially this part: `(select avg(gpa) from j)` your `j` alias doesn't yet exist

Comment: but `j.gpa` etc seems to work in select ? why is that then ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT major, 
       sname, 
       Max(gpa), 
       Avg(gpa) AS avg_gpa 
FROM   (SELECT s.*, 
               a.cname, 
               a.major, 
               a.decision 
        FROM   student s 
               JOIN apply a 
                 ON s.sid = a.sid 
                    AND a.decision = 'y') j 
GROUP  BY major 
HAVING Max(gpa) < avg_gpa;
```

This is due to j is the alias of the select query and you are using it in the above select query before initialize it. as first it will execute the sub query then select the column from there. And in that this table will not found.

Comment: i have edited my post to reflect what im trying this for. Your code works , but it isnt what i'm trying for. my question is regarding why the alias `j` does not work in the select subquery.

Comment: @SomjitNag also see this link http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/using-subquery-alias-in-column-operation-815284.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT major, 
       sname, 
       Max(gpa), 
       Avg(gpa) AS avgA 
FROM   (SELECT s.*, 
               a.cname, 
               a.major, 
               a.decision 
        FROM   student s 
               JOIN apply a 
                ON s.sid = a.sid 
                   AND decision = 'y') j 
GROUP  BY major 
HAVING Max(gpa) < avga;
```